# How to do File IO using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which needs to append to a file in local directory.

This extension is for internal purpose only. 
Using chrome app is not a feasible solution as they are getting deprecated.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: This question is asked regularly. Extensions can't write to local files directly except for the sandboxed HTML5 FileSystem inside the browser data dir. The only solution is to create a separate external utility (you can use node.js) and control it via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).